# I Can't access localhost:8080 after configuring tomcat on CentOS linux

Tags: linux, tomcat, centos

I have configured tomcat on Linux Centos but I can't access it on browser.

I configured server.xml, JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME.

This is what happens when I do ./catalina.sh

[image]

please let me know if more information is needed to help troubleshoot

Thanks

@Carlos

Here is the Cat.out log after I do ./startup.sh command

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried startup.sh instead ? 
or ./catalina.sh run | start

Comment: ./startup.sh does start Tomcat. i still cannot access Localhost:8080 however. Thanks

Comment: What appear in the Tomcat log files ./logs/catalina.out ? 
Maybe you have problems with SELinux or iptables blocking port 8080.

Comment: Carlos, log file has been added to my original post. Thanks